# What design pattern should I use to pass information between multiple dialogs in a desktop app?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, desktop

I am working on a CRUD application using .NET and I have about 10 or so dialogs I must implement.  The user will enter information on one dialog and be sent to another dialog depending on the information being passed.  This application basically mirrors what Spring MVC and JSF do when passing information between JSP pages.

Is there a design pattern I can use along with the MVC pattern/architecture that will help me transfer information between dialogs?

Comment: Are they true dialogs where they appear in response to the user interacting with the UI or are they separate forms simultaneous existing on the screen? Or both?

Comment: They are true dialogs where they appear in response to user interactions with the UI.  There are no simultaneous forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). If the dependencies between the observers start to be a too big mess, consider switching to [Mediator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

The [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) is useful in many of these situations.

Answer (score 0):

Might want to consider an [Application Controller](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/applicationController.html) pattern. (Also [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304764.aspx)) Also, I don't know exactly what your program is doing (ie. what the result at the end of the chain of dialogs is) but this pattern, in conjunction with the [Builder](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternBuilder.aspx) pattern works well.